# Using http format in sending XML message to client/server

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to create a client-server application that would communicate
using xml in a http format.

I already researched about client-server transferring file using TCP/IP.
It uses tcclient/tcplistener which worked very fine. However I was trying to
build an application that could use an http format of request to do the transferring of file.

I also had downloaded some codes for an implementation of an http server
but the http client needs to be a web browser, is there a way that I could just have a c# windows FORM as a client and pass those http webrequest/webresponse classes ?

Is there any suggestion that you can give?

Thank you very much in advance.
I hope you could help.

Comment: Go with WCF - gives you the most flexibility. You can have SOAP or REST, any transport (http, tcp/ip, msmq etc.) - it gives you a whole toolset to use

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're doing here is basically reinventing Web Services. For .NET, you can either look at [ASMX Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972326.aspx) or at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324).

Answer (score 0):

I also think should have a look at `Windows Communication Foundation`, it gives a lot of possibilities, settings and `security`. I recommend the following books to read,  that also helped me:

- [Professional WCF 4: Windows Communication Foundation with .NET 4
  (Wrox Programmer to Programmer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470563141)
- [Programming WCF Services, Third Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805494)

Hope it helps you.